# finding a word in a read only box selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

```
<textarea id="value(Orders21)" class="readonly" style="width: 98%;" readonly="readonly" rows="10" cols="20" name="value(Orders21)">HOMEBOUND REASONS: NEEDS ASSISTANCE</textarea>
```

hey guys this is the what showed up on firebug in a page i was working on.

I was wondering how do I make a condition to tell me that this read only text box contains the word "HOMEBOUND REASONS:"

```
if "HOMEBOUND REASONS:" in driver.page_source():
    print("it's there")
else:
    ("nope not here")
```

this produces this error (TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)

how do I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• First find the element

• Find text of it

• Do the logical comparison.

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id('value(Orders21)')

if "HOMEBOUND REASONS:" in element.text:
    print("it's there")
else:
    ("nope not here")
```

Comment: Glad it helped. text lets you grab the `innnerText` of the element

Answer (score 1):

You could find a list of elements with an xpath expression, then test the size of the list returned by the `find_elements_by_`:

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='readonly' and contains(text(), 'HOMEBOUND REASONS')]")
if len(elements) > 0:
    print("it's there")
else:
    print("nope not here")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I understand that you're code only checks if something is there. but I needed to check if the word "HOMEBOUND REASONS:" was specifically there. Thank you for taking your time though

Comment: @HalcyonAbrahamRamirez The part of the xpath expression `and contains(text(), 'HOMEBOUND REASONS')` specifically tests to see if the `textarea` contains the text you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id('value(Orders21)')

if "HOMEBOUND REASONS:" in element.text:
    print("it's there")
else:
    ("nope not here")
```

here is the explanation for the above code:

this is to locate the element in the page

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id('value(Orders21)')
```

next is the if condition to verify the particular element is found or not

```
 if "HOMEBOUND REASONS:" in element.text:
        print("it's there")
    else:
        ("nope not here")
```

here `element.text` is to obtain the text that is present in the element/object and then we are comparing particular string whether it is present in that element text or not